# how to replace +xx in pandas str replace

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using `Python 2.7.12` and `pandas 0.20.3`, I have a data frame like below, I want to replace column called number, this column dtype is object, when I try to replace `+91` in that column I'm getting error like below,

```
          number
0  +9185600XXXXX
1  +9199651XXXXX
2     99211XXXXX
3     99341XXXXX
4  +9199651XXXXX
```

`sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat`

full trace,

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "encoder.py", line 21, in 
>       df['number']=df['number'].str.replace('+91','')
>     File "/home/hduser/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/strings.py", line 1574, in replace
>       flags=flags)
>     File "/home/hduser/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/strings.py", line 424, in str_replace
>       regex = re.compile(pat, flags=flags)
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 194, in compile
>       return _compile(pattern, flags)
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 251, in _compile
>       raise error, v # invalid expression
>   sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat

But when I replace `91` it works as I expected, It's not working when I put `+` in prefix, 
Please help me to solve this problem.

Error Occurs at,

```
df['number']=df['number'].str.replace('+91','')
```

---

Comment: Pass `regex=False` ? eg: `.str.replace('+91','', regex=False)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can escape special regex value `+` (`one or more repetitions`) like:

```
df['number'] = df['number'].str.replace('\+91','')
```

Or use parameter `regex=False`:

```
df['number'] = df['number'].str.replace('+91','', regex=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
data={'number':['+9185600XXXXX','+9199651XXXXX']}
f=pd.DataFrame(data)
f['number']=f['number'].str.replace('\+91','')
print(f)
```