# how to remove string after integer in a dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas

[image]I want to remove string(subject to approval) after integer(90) in a dataframe.

```py
import pandas as pd
name_dict = {
            'Name': ['a','b','c','d'],
            'Score': ['90(subject to approval)',80,95,20]
          }
df = pd.DataFrame(name_dict)
print (df)

df.set_index('Name').loc['a', 'Score']
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to replace +xx in pandas str replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52384190/how-to-replace-xx-in-pandas-str-replace)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex to replace all non numeric characters and then cast to int.

```
import pandas as pd
name_dict = {
            'Name': ['a','b','c','d'],
            'Score': ['90(subject to approval)',80,95,20]
          }
df = pd.DataFrame(name_dict)

df['Score'] = df['Score'].replace(r'[^0-9]+', '', regex=True)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  Name  Score
0    a     90
1    b     80
2    c     95
3    d     20
```

If you want to only remove the extra string for rows where "Name" == "a" you can use:

```
import pandas as pd
name_dict = {
            'Name': ['a','b','c','d'],
            'Score': ['90(subject to approval)',80,95,20]
          }
df = pd.DataFrame(name_dict)

df.loc[df['Name'] == 'a', 'Score'] = (
    df
    .loc[df['Name'] == 'a', 'Score']
    .replace(r'[^0-9]+', '', regex=True)
)
```

Comment: Thanks mate. This works. but I want to use this regex logic only for Name 'a' and not for rest of the Name and score. How can we do that?

Comment: If you want to change the scores only for "Name" == "a" you can use `df.loc[df['Name'] == 'a', 'Score'] = df.loc[df['Name'] == 'a', 'Score'].replace(r'[^0-9]+', '', regex=True).astype(int)`

Comment: Hi Zach, one doubt, lets say score of name 'a' = 0.95 The float value is missing with above regex. how can we solve it?

Comment: you can remove the `.astype(int)` and it will keep decimal values.  I have edited the code above to reflect this.

Comment: If you want to make sure the result values are numeric you can do this:
`df.loc[df['Name'] == 'a', 'Score'] = pd.to_numeric(df.loc[df['Name'] == 'a', 'Score'].replace(r'[^0-9]+', '', regex=True))`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.str.extract` to extract the integer part

```py
df['Score'] = df['Score'].astype(str).str.extract('(\d+)')
```

```
print(df)

  Name Score
0    a    90
1    b    80
2    c    95
3    d    20
```